# Request for information about certain linear transformations of functions on subsets

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose I have an infinite set $U$ and let $M$ be the linear subspace of all real-valued functions $\nu$ on $2^U$ such that $\nu(\emptyset) = 0$. Here the sum of two such functions (and the product of such a function by a scalar) is taken simply; i.e. pointwise.

Now fix a member $\bar{\nu} \in M$. I am interested in linear transformations $T_{\bar{\nu}}$ of $M$ into itself of the following form: $$(T_{\bar{\nu}}\nu)(S) = \bar{\nu}(S)(\nu(S)), \quad S \subset U.$$ I would like to know if these types of transformations (or equivalent) have been studied before and, if so, under what name. Note I am not requiring that $\bar{\nu}$ be a measure, or even an outer measure, but would be willing to start there.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.